# rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages Crash

Tags: ios, openssl, webrtc

When I use WebTRTC Video, I got the delegate method, And I got the RTCICEGatheringState == RTCICEGatheringComplete, then Crashed. Please help me.

peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection iceGatheringChanged:(RTCICEGatheringState)newState

```
* thread #28, name = 'Thread 0x0x10a706e70', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    frame #0: 0x00000001864085a4 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break
    frame #1: 0x00000001864081bc libsystem_malloc.dylib`nano_common_error + 240
  * frame #2: 0x00000001863fc890 libsystem_malloc.dylib`nanov2_allocate_from_block$VARIANT$mp + 548
    frame #3: 0x00000001863fbc1c libsystem_malloc.dylib`nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$mp + 176
    frame #4: 0x00000001863fbb1c libsystem_malloc.dylib`nanov2_malloc$VARIANT$mp + 60
    frame #5: 0x00000001863f7828 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_zone_malloc + 156
    frame #6: 0x00000001863f8c0c libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc + 32
    frame #7: 0x0000000103366954 qim_appstore`bn_wexpand + 84
    frame #8: 0x000000010336f0d4 qim_appstore`BN_lshift + 84
    frame #9: 0x0000000103367ee4 qim_appstore`BN_div + 384
    frame #10: 0x0000000103368320 qim_appstore`BN_nnmod + 52
    frame #11: 0x00000001033684ac qim_appstore`BN_mod_mul + 132
    frame #12: 0x00000001033857e8 qim_appstore`ec_GFp_simple_is_on_curve + 260
    frame #13: 0x000000010337ad8c qim_appstore`EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates_GFp + 112
    frame #14: 0x000000010337a778 qim_appstore`EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name + 664
    frame #15: 0x000000010337bd44 qim_appstore`EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name + 40
    frame #16: 0x000000010338b240 qim_appstore`eckey_type2param + 92
    frame #17: 0x000000010338aa70 qim_appstore`eckey_pub_decode + 92
    frame #18: 0x00000001033a6d1c qim_appstore`X509_PUBKEY_get + 148
    frame #19: 0x00000001033b5ff4 qim_appstore`ssl3_get_server_certificate + 468
    frame #20: 0x00000001033b2114 qim_appstore`dtls1_connect + 1160
    frame #21: 0x000000010351d8f0 qim_appstore`rtc::OpenSSLStreamAdapter::ContinueSSL() + 164
    frame #22: 0x000000010351d59c qim_appstore`rtc::OpenSSLStreamAdapter::OnEvent(rtc::StreamInterface*, int, int) + 572
    frame #23: 0x0000000103526860 qim_appstore`sigslot::signal3<rtc::StreamInterface*, int, int, sigslot::single_threaded>::operator()(rtc::StreamInterface*, int, int) + 96
    frame #24: 0x000000010353a928 qim_appstore`cricket::StreamInterfaceChannel::OnPacketReceived(char const*, unsigned long) + 60
    frame #25: 0x000000010353d108 qim_appstore`cricket::DtlsTransportChannelWrapper::HandleDtlsPacket(char const*, unsigned long) + 84
    frame #26: 0x000000010353af3c qim_appstore`cricket::DtlsTransportChannelWrapper::OnReadPacket(cricket::TransportChannel*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::PacketTime const&, int) + 88
    frame #27: 0x000000010353d084 qim_appstore`sigslot::signal5<cricket::TransportChannel*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::PacketTime const&, int, sigslot::single_threaded>::operator()(cricket::TransportChannel*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::PacketTime const&, int) + 116
    frame #28: 0x0000000103541264 qim_appstore`cricket::P2PTransportChannel::OnReadPacket(cricket::Connection*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::PacketTime const&) + 84
    frame #29: 0x000000010354ce90 qim_appstore`sigslot::signal4<cricket::Connection*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::PacketTime const&, sigslot::single_threaded>::operator()(cricket::Connection*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::PacketTime const&) + 108
    frame #30: 0x000000010354ca54 qim_appstore`cricket::Connection::OnReadPacket(char const*, unsigned long, rtc::PacketTime const&) + 216
    frame #31: 0x00000001035784a4 qim_appstore`cricket::UDPPort::HandleIncomingPacket(rtc::AsyncPacketSocket*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::SocketAddress const&, rtc::PacketTime const&) + 12
    frame #32: 0x000000010350b0dc qim_appstore`sigslot::signal5<rtc::AsyncPacketSocket*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::SocketAddress const&, rtc::PacketTime const&, sigslot::single_threaded>::operator()(rtc::AsyncPacketSocket*, char const*, unsigned long, rtc::SocketAddress const&, rtc::PacketTime const&) + 116
    frame #33: 0x000000010350b608 qim_appstore`rtc::AsyncUDPSocket::OnReadEvent(rtc::AsyncSocket*) + 112
    frame #34: 0x0000000103523090 qim_appstore`sigslot::signal1<rtc::AsyncSocket*, sigslot::multi_threaded_local>::ope

    rator()(rtc::AsyncSocket*) + 76
        frame #35: 0x00000001035202b0 qim_appstore`rtc::SocketDispatcher:

:OnEvent(unsigned int, int) + 120
    frame #36: 0x0000000103520a9c qim_appstore`rtc::PhysicalSocketServer::Wait(int, bool) + 852
    frame #37: 0x0000000103513804 qim_appstore`rtc::MessageQueue::Get(rtc::Message*, int, bool) + 816
    frame #38: 0x0000000103527d70 qim_appstore`rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages(int) + 108
    frame #39: 0x0000000103527bfc qim_appstore`rtc::Thread::PreRun(void*) + 112
    frame #40: 0x000000018643b1e4 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 128
    frame #41: 0x000000018643b164 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 40
    frame #42: 0x000000018643a070 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4
```